# Can the phrasal verb "wear into" used this way?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

"I don't want dad to use my shoes. He **wears them into** his own size making them loose for me to put on."

I am using "wear into" to mean the same as [wear in](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/wear-in#:%7E:text=To%20put%20on%20or%20be%20wearing%20clothes%20and%20to%20dress%20other%20people).

Comment: No. The verb is "*wear something **in***", with no object, not "*wear something **into***" with an object.

Comment: @gotube Thanks! I got it. Can u please paste this as answer so I can close the question?

Comment: I've answered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The verb is "wear something in", with no object, not "wear something into" with an object.